# Post edited while I'm working on my edit - closing the popup

Tags: bug, edits

Occasionally, while I edit a post, a popup along the top of the screen comes up indicating that another user has already edited this post and that my edit will only be accepted if it is more substantial than the previous one.  Fair game.  However when I submit my edit - and it is more substantial than the previous one - the edit is accepted and the post shows my edits.  Yet the popup along the top of the screen remains.  I would expect it to close automatically if I satisfied the requirement and it's no longer applicable.

Answer (score -1):

Just refresh the page.

It's the same if there is a new comment or answer: the `There are N new answers/comments` banner will show up, but if the answer/comment was deleted by the time you click the banner to load them, the banner doesn't change. It would be too many requests to the server to check for answers/comments/edits/close votes to be deleted.

Comment: Of course refreshing the page will solve it. This is different from _There are N new answers_, because those answers are not automatically shown when I submit my edit.  Here, the action that prompt the banner is no longer applicable - and the notification on the banner itself is no longer applicable, because my edit overwrote that edit.

Comment: This is a bad solution for those with slow or bandwidth-limited connections.